# Superclass behaviour doesn't apply as expected to the Penguin object

Tags: c#, subclass, superclass

Any thoughts on why altitude is not 5 at the end of this program? 
So I have a Penguin class deriving from Birds, and in Birds class I have a check on whether the birds is flightless, and based on that I reset the given altitude to 0 or keep the provided altitude.
Supposing penguins can fly (isFlightless=false), Penguin.ArrangeBirdInPatterns(p); should trigger the ArrangeBirdInTheSky, which it does, and then the altitude should be the one I provided (=5), not zero.

My VS crashed and I'm using online fiddlers, hard to debug.

```
using System;

public class Bird {
    public double altitude;
    public bool isFlightless;
    public virtual void setLocation(double longitude, double latitude) {
    }
    public virtual void setAltitude(double altitude) {
        this.altitude = altitude;
    }

    public void ArrangeBirdOnGround()
    {
        setAltitude(0);
    }
    public void ArrangeBirdInTheSky()
    {
        setAltitude(altitude);
    }
    public static void ArrangeBirdInPatterns(Bird b)
    {
        if(b.isFlightless)
        {
            b.ArrangeBirdOnGround();
        }
        else
        {
            b.ArrangeBirdInTheSky();
        }
    }

};

public class Penguin : Bird
{
    public override void setAltitude(double altitude) {

    }
}


public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        Bird p = new Penguin();
        p.setAltitude(5);
        p.isFlightless = false;
        Penguin.ArrangeBirdInPatterns(p);
        Console.WriteLine(p.altitude);  //// returns 0. why not 5

    }
}
```

Also, why can't I call it like: ArrangeBirdInPatterns(p); if I remove static from the ArrangeBirdInPatterns definition?

Comment: You forgot to put a language tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling Penguin's setAltitude, which does nothing.
The type of `p` is `Bird`, but the type of the value contained there is `Penguin`, which overrides `Bird.setAltitude`, so that's what gets called.

You can look into the differences between virtual, override, and new keywords for more info on the different ways to subclass.